how do i open trading and sniping/buying token in same bundle
i saw a lot of people launch tokens after adding liquidity to uniswap and then snipe/buy the first few buys as a bundle ( they know in advance how much it will cost them so they disperse x amount of eth to each wallet in advance)
anyone can help with that?

It is usually done with insider info. The details are distributed in private channels to potential investors.
